# Install an occupancy sensor, old switch has 3 black wires

Tags: switch, motion-sensor

I have an odd situation. I bought a simple occupancy sensor switch but when I opened it up there's an additional red load wire. The existing switch has 3 black wires and the neutral and ground are tied to each other in the box. How do I install the occupancy sensor?

[image: occupant sensor install]

Comment: The neutral and ground are tied to each other in the box?  I can't really see from the picture, with the paint and all.  Are you saying the bare wires are spliced to the white wires?

Comment: The white are spliced together and the ground are spliced together separately. There are three wire bundles going through the box, and only black is connected to the switch. The switch controls one light only and it is not a 3 way. This is a condo that was built in the mid 80s

Answer (score 1):

> **WARNING:** This procedure requires working on live wiring. If you're not comfortable with that, contact a local licensed Electrician.

Turn the light switch off, then use a multimeter/voltmeter to check for voltage between the ground and the terminals on the switch. One terminal will read line voltage (120 volts), while the other should read 0 volts.

Once you know what's what, turn off power to the circuit and verify that it's off.

The terminal that reads line voltage, is the line side terminal.  If that's the terminal with one wire, attach the single wire to the black wire of the new switch. If it's the terminal with two wires, attach both of those wires to the black wire of the new switch.

Attach the wire(s) from the other terminal (the 0 volt terminal), to the red (load) wire of the new switch.

Connect the white wire from the new switch, in with the other white wires in the box. Connect the green wire from the new switch, in with the other grounds in the box.

Use twist-on wire connectors, or other approved means to make the connections. Make sure you use connectors rated for the number, and size of wires you're connecting.

Comment: Also, the bundle of white wires in the box will need to be undone and attached to the white wire on the new occupancy sensor.

Comment: Oh, and rather than test a live circuit, I think an assumption can be made.  If the switch controls two lights, the single black wire is "hot".  If it only controls one light, the pair of black wires is hot and the single wire is "load".

Comment: @JPhi1618 I prefer not to assume, especially when it comes to electrical.

Comment: Tester 101, thanks. Does this wiring diagram match your instruction? http://waterheatertimer.org/images/Motion-detector-1.jpg